# Removing UserDefaults-generated plist file when running unit tests

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, xctest, userdefaults

I'm testing a class that depends on an instance of UserDefaults. In following this sample code found [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/avoiding-mocking-userdefaults/), I create and setup the instance like so:

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: #file)
    defaults.removePersistentDomain(forName: #file)
}
```

After running the tests, a plist file is created within the same directory as this test class. If my testing file is named `TestFile.swift` the plist is given the name `TestFile.swift.plist`. I'm pretty sure this is generated at the call of the `suiteName:` initializer above. My question is: how do I remove this file once the tests have completed? I've tried making calls to `removeSuite(named: #file)`, `removeVolatileDomain(forName: #file)`, and `removePersistentDomain(forName: #file)` within the test's `tearDown` method but no luck. Calling `synchronize()` didn't seem to help either.

Comment: Just like any plist value you need to nil it out to get rid of it. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, instead of passing in an actual instance of `UserDefaults`, you would instead pass a different type of object that doesn't require that cleanup.  A simple example would be something like:

```
class UnitTestDefaults: UserDefaults {

    private var values = [String: Any]()

    // override only the functions you need, e.g.

    override func object(forKey defaultName: String) -> Any? {
        values[defaultName]
    }

    override func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String) {
        values[defaultName] = value
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you could define a new protocol and have the object you're testing depend on an instance of that protocol instead of `UserDefaults`.  This would be considered more proper practice for unit testing, and would also solve your problem if simply creating an instance of `UserDefaults`, even a subclass that doesn't define a custom suite, still has unwanted side effects.

```
protocol DefaultsStorage {
    func object(forKey defaultName: String) -> Any?
    func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String)
}

class UnitTestDefaults: DefaultsStorage {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a test target so committing it shouldn't be a worry. Once it's committed once there's no need to worry about it again.

Probably a good idea to nil it out on teardown if you want to make sure you leave a clean state between runs.

```
override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        try super.tearDownWithError()
        mockDefaults()
    }
```

Here `mockDefaults()` calls to pass a value of `nil` which yields a plist with:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

It calls:

```
private extension FakeInrangeTests {
    func mockDefaults(value: Bool? = nil) -> UserDefaults {
        MockDefaults.makeInrange(#file, value)
    }
}
```

Which calls:

```
struct MockDefaults {
    static func make(
        _ file: String,
        value: Any? = nil,
        key: String?
    ) -> UserDefaults {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: file)!
        userDefaults.removePersistentDomain(forName: file)
        if let value = value, let key = key {
            userDefaults.setValue(value, forKey: key)
        }
        return userDefaults
    }
}

extension MockDefaults {
    static func makeInrange(
        _ file: String,
        _ value: Bool?
    ) -> UserDefaults {
        MockDefaults.make(
            file,
            value: value,
            key: UserDefaults.fakeInrangeKey
        )
    }
}
```

You can add it to your .gitignore.

`*.swift.plist`

You can confirm that the plist is not removed by running

```
var defaults: UserDefaults!

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        continueAfterFailure = false
        try super.setUpWithError()
        defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: #file)
        defaults.setValue(12, forKey: "myKey")
    }
    
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        try super.tearDownWithError()
        defaults.removePersistentDomain(forName: #file)
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why it should be so complex regarding the cleaning plist file. Wouldn't just a call of userDefaults.removePersistentDomain(forName: file) in tearDown work? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I updated my post with some sample code you can easily run to test this for yourself @Werewolf